# dpdk library Linking issue

Tags: dpdk

Default installation of dpdk using Meson,Ninja will provide libdpdk.pc.Please provide suggestion in linking dpdk library in Cmakefile  dpdk version 20.11.2.

```
cmake

    Checking for libdpdk
    Found libdpdk,version 20.11.2
```

make Error Message:

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include/x86intrin.h:37:0,
from /usr/local/include/rte_vect.h:31,
from /usr/local/include/rte_memcpy.h:17,
from /home/sample.c:88,
```

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include/tmmintrin.h:185:1:
error: inlining failed in call to always_inline ‘_mm_alignr_epi8’: target specific option mismatch

libdpdk.pc

```
prefix=/usr/local
libdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
includedir=${prefix}/include
Name:DPDK
Requires:libdpdk-libs
Cflags:-I{includedir}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
    find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
    pkg_check_modules(DPDK REQUIRED libdpdk)
    include_directories(${DPDK_INCLUDE_DIR})
    include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
    link_directories(${DPDK_LIBRARY_DIR})
set(DPDK_LIBS "-Wl,--whole-archive -l dpdk -Wl,--no-whole-archive")

    add_executable(sample sample.c)
   # target_include_directories(sample PUBLIC /usr/local/include)
    #target_include_directories(sample PUBLIC /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu)
    target_link_libraries(sample PUBLIC ${DPDK_LIBS})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -mssse3")
```

in `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution..I could solve it by setting CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS to msse4.2".

Comment: setting CMAKE_C_FLAGS to -mssse3 was generating same error .setting CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS to msse4.2 solved the issue.